# How to know whether the subscription payload was reached on AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am doing a data synchronisation between two clients, where I put several items into GraphQL with batch operations (Around 5 Batch of 25 operations each).

All Requests went through and the data provided in the requests were stored successfully in the data source. However, In the second client only 3 or 4 of these batch requests arrived.

This is my resolver for the batch operations

```
#set($currentTime = $util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds())
#set($identityId = $ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId)
#set($syncData = [])
#foreach($item in ${ctx.args.input.items})
    #set($item['timestamp'] = $currentTime)
    #set($item['author'] = $identityId)
    $util.qr($syncData.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($item)))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "PWM_Sync_DS": $utils.toJson($syncData)
    }
}
```

I think the problem comes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_appsync) where it says that the limit for Subscription payload is 128 Kb.

**My Question(s)**
How can I see or check the Subscription payload Size of an operation? reaching the limit actually prevents subscription to be send?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the troubles. Unfortunately, AppSync doesn't expose an error if the subscription payload was too large today. That is, however, a totally reasonable ask and I'll bring it back to the team as a request for a future release.

Comment: any update in this feature request?